# How to view the system console message after Blender crashes?

Tags: command-line

I am testing a script in Blender game engine. I can view the helpful message on the external system console when the script throws exception. Sometimes the bugs of the script cause the Blender to crash and close the console immediately.

Is there any way to view the message after the Blender crashes? How to write the message to a text file for later viewing? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13):

- On windows just run blender from Command Prompt:

  <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

  In field type *cmd* and hit OK. Inside the console navigate to your blender.exe with command

  `cd c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\` (or whatever your path is)
   
  instead you can also navigate to the folder in the Explorer and SHIFT+Rightclick on the Folder and select `Open Comand Promt here`

  and then type `blender.exe`

  You can also [use command line arguments](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html).

  Now even if Blender crashes, you will still see the program output in the console.
- On OSX use Terminal app and run it like

  ```
  cd /Applications/Blender
  ./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender
  ```
- On Linux open terminal and run

  ```
  cd <blender installation directory>
  ./blender
  ```

You can start `blender` (or `blender.exe`) with the option `--factory-startup` attached to check if a addon or a setting caused the crash

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it worked

cd "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"<br>
blender<br>

Comment: On vista and windows 7 you do not have to open the run window. You can type `cmd` in to the start menu and press enter.

Answer (score 7):

Start blender from a console / cmd prompt in the first place and if it crashes, it will just return to the console and not close the console.

For windows i set up a **bat** file to load cmd.exe, with any of these variants:

`start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\blender_trunk\blender.exe --debug-all`

`start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\blender_trunk\blender.exe --debug`

`start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\blender_trunk\blender.exe`

It will load the cmd prompt, then blender, and depending on how much info you want you add the [debug flag](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line#Debug_Options:). Make a shortcut to the bat file, and all you have to do is click it to start Blender + console

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried and found that the quote should be as follows:

`start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" --debug-all`<br>

it was a minor typo that may confuse others who may want to try your suggestion.

Comment: @ShungChing the quote in my post is exactly how I have it on my system, but it appears the quotes can be dropped entirely.

Comment: If there is a space in the path, it must be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought! my original path doesn't have spaces so the quotes aren't even needed, whereas @ShungChing's path is program<space>files

Answer (score 1):

Go to the *Menu Bar > Windows* and click on *Toggle System Console*

Comment: Please note the Toggle System Console menu item exists only for  Microsoft Windows OS builds of blender.