# GPU compute not working in Mac Book Pro with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB

Tags: rendering, gpu

Blender 2.77 not rendering with GPU compute in mac book pro with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M graphics and Intel Iris Pro Built-in graphics.
2.5 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB 1600MHz DDR3.
after starting the render its shows--

first for about 2 minutes the status line shows --'Loading render kernels(may take a few minutes the first time)’  after that a message is displayed -
' cycles render GPU Compute. Calculation is finished.'

then in the status area it shows-  'OpenCL build failed: errors in console.'

is this graphics card not supported in blender?

what can I do to use the GPU render.

Comment: In the System preferences did you set the Compute Device to use Cuda? What are the errors reported on the console? To access the console see this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're trying to use OpenCl as opposed to CUDA. Change your render option to CUDA in Blender Preferences. If that doesn't work, try updating blender to 2.77a.

Comment: I have the same setup, and don't see a CUDA option even after installing the CUDA drivers from Nvidia's website. Is there something else I have to install?