# Why does Blender gets frozen once I rotate an object and then crash?

Tags: windows, installation

Yesterday I installed Blender on my PC with these characteristics:

[image: system stats]

My problem is that Blender crashes when I open it. First it gets frozen when I try to rotate any object and then it crashes. I don't know what to do.

Comment: it is going to be hard for any of us to help you. Blender normally runs fine. At this point anything here will just be guessing. Do you have a Nivida M series gpu?

Comment: what OS are you running ?

Comment: Is there a crash log in your temp folder.  [Start blender from a console](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes/21778#21778), and note any messages written there.

Comment: Does it freeze when you do other things, like move objects around or create them?

Comment: If Blender is crashing in such simplistic task it is for sure an issue with either your computer, your hardware or your software. More specifically I smell bad graphics drivers. Please edit your question and provide a full information of your system specs including graphics cards brand, model, and drivers version, your image seems to be incomplete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is most likely cause by an issue with your computer, hardware, software, or drivers.

Comment: I had this issue recently. Turned out it was because of a new nvidia driver update. I did a rollback on the driver. And it was back to normal. I suggest you try doing the same

Answer (score 0):

I suggest deleting all evidence of Blender from your computer and trying to reinstall. it may be a fact of repeated downloads or simply that your computer's software is not designed on the same framework as Blender. it may also be an idea to clean out your computer as it may be a stray program interfering with the startup. check in detail the running requirements of Blender before installing and make sure that instillation.
It may very well be that your software cannot handle blender, or that you somehow managed to download a damaged version of the files