# Shortest path key makes edges freestyle instead

Tags: shortcut

I use a heavily modified shortcuts for blender. I have set "select shortest path" to ctrl+right click and it has worked for a long time until today. 
I am not aware of changing anything recently but suddenly instead of "shortest path" the above shortcut does something weird:
-selects the shortest path
-makes all selected edges freestyle edges
-deselects all

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: That is quite localized situation. Obvisouly there is some conflict between these 2 actions, so search for the key binding for them both and see if there are some interesting details.

Comment: I did an extensive search... freestyle edges are not assigned to anything. There are no conflicting bindings. Boggles my mind.

Comment: That might be a bug but likely something with shortcuts as you wrote you use "heavily modified ones. Ctrl+Right Click is default setting for Pick Shortest Path so there's something else going on. Try opening Blender from the command line in debug mode, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes, repeat actions with selecting that path and see what is logged in the console window, probably it will write something useful. Note also that Pick Shortest Path has options in the F6 menu, maybe they are changed.

Comment: I found nothing pertaining to the problem in the console. Nevertheless I have edited my original question with all the warnings that show up in the console when I start blender.

Comment: All that noise is a distraction, it is output that you will see every time you run blender, it is from addon changes that still have settings saved in your startup file. If you expand the [info editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/introduction.html#report-console) you should see the name of the operator called by the shortcut, which may help.

Comment: Yes, did that. All it shows is the shortest path operation:
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_pick(use_face_step=False, use_topology_distance=False, use_fill=False, index=935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix, I had same problem for  a while where shortest path edge select marked them as freestyle

Apparently I have changed some options on Edge Select mode and forgot. Hope this fixes it

[image]