# Blender has closed when I re-openig some files

Tags: blend-files

when I open my saved file it's opened... but when exit the rendered show in uv view and went to the 3D view,  my left click and middle muse work correctly and when i Right click on my object to select it, the program get closed without any error. This Happening is for some saved files, not all of them... and I do the same saving method for all of them. what should i do? 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oPoy.jpg]

Comment: It's likely not enough hardware resources, RAM specifically. If the mesh which has 1,2 mln faces as shown one causes Blender to close when it's gets selected it means Blender can't allocate memory. Try opening Blender from console and see what does it write there after crash, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes

Comment: thank... when i reduce the modifier subsurface's view its worked... my subdivided was 5... but now is ok

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me too.Sometimes the file gets corrupted.Try copying your object in a new empty blender file and then save it with a different name.It worked for me.

Comment: i try it but that happens again... but when i reduce the modifier subsurface's view its worked.      by the way thanks for your attention