# Blender Cycles - Crash while synchronizing objects, Not even close to running out of memory

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to render a scene with 265,189 faces, using 4K textures. Half the time I try and render a frame, blender will suddenly close without an error message or crash log. I am rendering on GPU, but this error occurs on CPU as well.

Blender will close while "synchronizing objects"

here is what my task manager says while rendering:

[image: Here is what my task manager says while rendering]

Specs:

8 Gigabytes of ram

GTX 970 graphics card

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is what my command prompt says. This was after it successfully rendered 2 frames.
[image]

Comment: It is clear that there is something wrong but it doesn't seem to be enough information to troubleshoot. Try to run Blender [from command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes) to see error it writes into console after crash. Edit the question with error text and screenshot afterwards.

Comment: Of you are rendering using GPU. VRAM Memory usage will not show in the task manager. Use a dedicated app that can area the memory usage from the graphics card

Comment: Using GPU-Z, I am looking at using around 50% of my Vram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by un-installing "jiggle armature 2" addon. I just completed a 250+ frame render with no crashes.

Comment: you should let the addon's author know about the issue.