# Cant open blender

Tags: error, startup-file

I've downloaded blender multiple times and everytime I try to open the program it pops up with a grey screen for half a second and then disappears and I can't get it  to open and I can't use it.

Comment: Could you include your operating system and what version of blender you are downloading?

Comment: im using windows 10 and its blender 2.79

Comment: Open it by typing "blender" command in system console (terminal).  Report any errors listed in question.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes