# How can I start blender 2.8 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installation

I've downloaded Blender 2.8 and extracted files to a suitable folder. But when I double click on the 'Blender' program, nothing happens.
I used the same procedure with Blender 2.79b and that works just fine.

I need 2.80 as I'm having trouble with [MHX2](https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mhx2-makehuman-exchange) import in 2.79b - the addon is enabled but nothing appears under file import, and my understanding is that MHX2 was updated for Blender 2.80 and no longer works with 2.79b, and I can't seem to find an earlier version.

PS: it would be helpful if tags could be selected from dropdown menu or something  as I don't know all the names.

Comment: If you execute the binary from the console you should get a useful error message

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes

Comment: You can use the snap version of Blender. You just have to run `sudo snap install blender` then it will be ready for use. No extracting archives, no moving files.

Comment: just write down blender in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The version you downloaded might not be configured for your distribution. To see if there were some error messages you can open a Terminal window in the folder you extracted blender to by right clicking in the file browser and choosing "Open in Terminal". Then run the program by typing "./blender" (or whatever the program file is called), hit enter and see if there are any error messages.

However I would advise to install Blender from another source that has been tested with your OS instead. There is a PPA for newer versions of Blender maintained by Thomas Schiex: https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender
If you don't mind using the newer development version of Blender (2.81) it might be what you want. You can add a PPA to your system by following the instruction close to the bottom of the linked page or through the Synaptic package manager.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a ppa for security reasons. The official builds run fine on Ubuntu. The issue is likely somewhere else, e.g. unsupported hardware or old graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I now what is your problem. Because I had the same problem at the past.

You should update your drivers. Most importantly the graphics card.

My graphics card was AMD. So I downloaded the driver from AMD's internet site.