# Blender 2.9 won't open anymore

Tags: python

Blender 2.9 opened the first time I click on it I installed so older addons. It shut while I was installing addons, and would not open anymore, so I uninstalled and reinstalled blender many times, it still won't open. I reverted to a less recent version that still works.

Comment: Start blender from console, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes report any error messages in question

Answer (score 2):

Locate and delete the preferences files for 2.9.

The files you need to delete are *startup.blend*, *userpref.blend*, *bookmarks.txt*, *recent-files.txt*.

Read this link to find them on your system.
[Where is the startup file stored?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored)

Re-install blender and disable all adons.  If the program runs, only then start adding addons **one by one**, until you find the one that is creating the problem.

Once you find the problem you can report the bug to the developer of that particular addon.

If none of this works, then run blender in [debug mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#debug-options) and file a bug report with the info from the console.

[Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete everything related to blender and then reinstall it.